# Installed TWRP recovery on a Verizon-locked device but didn't unlock bootloader: options?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, twrp, odin, verizon

On a Verizon Galaxy S3, I installed the TWRP recovery not realizing Verizon's bootloader is locked. Now it boots to "System software not authorized by Verizon Wireless has been found on your phone. Please turn off your phone and go to the nearest Verizon Wireless store for help."

Short of actually going to the Verizon store and begging them to recover this phone, what are my options for recovering from this mess? I imagine if I could just rewrite the original recovery then I could use an easy unlocker app inside the OS. I did back that up before installing TWRP so there's that.

Worth noting: through some combination of buttons I did once get this to boot into Odin(?). It said it was downloading something but never seemed to finish. Not sure if that's helpful.